# Loadstring Error: attempted to call a nil value

Tags: lua

```
loadstring("
\45\45\32\80\117\116\32\115\99\114\105\112\116\32\104\101\114\101\10\112\114\105\110\116\40\34\104\105\34\41\10")()
```

I keep getting an error stating this:

```
lua: /tmp/044957038/main.lua:12: attempt to call a nil value (global 'loadstring')
stack traceback:
    /tmp/044957038/main.lua:12: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

Can anyone help me? (I’m using **glot.io** to run my script.)

Comment: On Lua 5.2+ use `load()`

Comment: Doesn’t work, comes up blank

Comment: [Test it](https://glot.io/snippets/fph5fhlooh).

Comment: nevermind, my code editor that i was using to run must be broken since its from like 2011 and not updated since

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/SmpFy3n . it wont work lol

Comment: You missed `()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and some testing in glot, this should work (the print() is just for reference):

```
print("\45\45\32\80\117\116\32\115\99\114\105\112\116\32\104\101\114\101\10\112\114\105\110\116\40\34\104\105\34\41\10")

load("\45\45\32\80\117\116\32\115\99\114\105\112\116\32\104\101\114\101\10\112\114\105\110\116\40\34\104\105\34\41\10")()
```

Output

```
-- Put script here
print("hi")

hi
```